# Plotting 2D and 3D data for a nonlinear system in mathematica

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I had to plot various nonlinear differential equations. But because of a large number of equations for large spans of time and other considerations, the program has become too heavy to be run on my system. Therefore I have been using a supercomputer to solve the data using C++(Supercomputer does not have Mathematica) and I wanted to plot that data using Mathematica.

I used 4th order Runga Kutta to solve the equations in C++ and I got the data which  I wanted to plot. For example, when plotting the Lorenz Equations I'm outputting data from C++ in the form

```
{{1,1,1},{1,1.025,0.9990},{1.000,1.051,0.9980},{1.000,1.077,0.9971},.........}
```

where {a,b,c} are the values of the x, y and z co-ordinate at a particular time.

But I have been unable to plot this data using any of the functions in Mathematica that I knew of. I could plot this as a single curve but I actually want to study the system and I wanted to plot this like a line moving from one data point to another. I also needed to plot the variable separately. I tried to use various function and even tried to interpolate the data but none of it seemed to work. Can anyone tell me how I could plot this or should I try something different.

I would be very grateful if you could.

Comment: how about `Graphics3D[{Line@{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1.025, 0.9990}, {1.000, 1.051, 
     0.9980}, {1.000, 1.077, 0.9971}}}, BoxRatios -> 1]`?

Comment: You could use `ListPlot[dat[[All, n]]]` to plot the n-th coordinate (assign your data the name `dat`).

Comment: maybe `ListPointPlot3D[data] /. 
 p : Point[x_] :> {PointSize[Large], Red, p, Blue, Arrowheads[.005], 
   Arrow /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]}`?